# Join 2 tables with WHERE that might not be present

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 simple tables:

- employees
- employee_reports

employees are expected to submit 1 report / day.

now, here's the need: 
See at a glance all the reports submitted by employees, the employees w/o a report will just show a blank REPORT field.. basically this means all employees will be listed regardless if they have report or not

example output on my GUI:

```
2012-01-03
Employee 1 : I ate a burger
Employee 2 : I ate french frice
Employee 3 : 
Employee 4 : i ate hotdog
```

I can easily do this in mulitple SQL queries.. 1 for listing all the employees in a specific order, and the other to query each report of an employee..

ofcourse that is not efficient..

I can easily make a LEFT JOIN of the employee_reports on the employee table, but

The problem: Since I have to target a specific report date, mYSQL outputs only the employees w/ a REPORT.. those who didnt submit are not listed.

here's a sample of my basic sql

```
SELECT
employees.eid,
employees.fname,
employees.lname,
employee_reports.report
FROM
employees
LEFT JOIN employee_reports ON employees.eid = employee_reports.eid
WHERE 
report_date = '2013-01-03'
```

Can I do this in one query?

Comment: Could you go back to your old questions, maybe +1 answers that helped you, and accept (the 'check' mark) the ones that are the best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your where needs to be able to check for the empty values as well, so make it

```
SELECT
employees.eid,
employees.fname,
employees.lname,
employee_reports.report
FROM
employees
LEFT JOIN employee_reports ON employees.eid = employee_reports.eid
WHERE 
report_date = '2013-01-03'
OR report_date IS NULL
```